# How can I remove a specific number of DOM elements on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to remove the four nearest div elements above a button when it is clicked (along with the div containing the button).  I have been trying to use `.closest()`, but have not had much luck.  I will always be removing the button itself and the four elements above the button in the DOM order.

There are multiple sets of rows with the divs below, so I cannot select these elements by class alone.

**Example HTML:**

```
//Row 1
<div class="col-2 selectedRow">014</div>
<div class="col-4 selectedRow">Test</div>
<div class="col-2 selectedRow">Special Charge</div>
<div class="col-2 selectedRow">012</div>
<div class="col-2 selectedRow"><input type="button" class="removeCode" value="Remove"></div>

//Row 2
<div class="col-2 selectedRow">012</div>
<div class="col-4 selectedRow">Test 2</div>
<div class="col-2 selectedRow">Other Charge</div>
<div class="col-2 selectedRow">011</div>
<div class="col-2 selectedRow"><input type="button" class="removeCode" value="Remove"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("form").on('click', '.removeCode', function (event) {
    //Remove the current div container, and the 4 divs above that element in the DOM order.
});
```

Comment: Why are they not grouped? If they were grouped, you would just go to the parent of the div that was clicked and simply remove it...

Comment: When trying to add a container around the row, it messes up all of the CSS formatting involved with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes to your HTML file such as:

1. replace your `input` element with `button` and apply same styles as wrapper `div`.
2. Surround individual row in a container
3. On click remove container from which button was clicked

for example:

```js
$("form .removeCode").click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent(".container").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-2 selectedRow">014</div>
    <div class="col-4 selectedRow">Test</div>
    <div class="col-2 selectedRow">Special Charge</div>
    <div class="col-2 selectedRow">012</div>
    <button type="button" class="col-2 selectedRow removeCode">Remove</button>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-2 selectedRow">012</div>
    <div class="col-4 selectedRow">Test 2</div>
    <div class="col-2 selectedRow">Other Charge</div>
    <div class="col-2 selectedRow">011</div>
    <button type="button" class="col-2 selectedRow removeCode">Remove</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I add a div container around the row, it messes up the formatting from the bootstrap grid system.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @sjohn285 Well, do you mean `tr` by row if yes, that is also a container and this code will work with tr as well but make sure to assign `container` class to row.